# How to format columns in laravel excel if i don't know the column letter

Tags: excel, laravel, export, laravel-blade

We are exporting an excel from a blade, the problem is that we perform a foreach cycle that renders a subtraction between two numbers. However when exporting they are as if they were string. All the examples that I find on the internet, involve knowing the column to be formatted, but as it is a range of dates it is impossible for me to know it beforehand.

[image: foreach]

[image: example]

Comment: *"it is impossible for me to know it beforehand."* - How so? You're clearly looping over _something_; record the column letter when you start, like `$col = 'J'`, then every iteration, you can increment it, like `$col++` ('K', then 'L', etc.), then format columns `J` through whatever `$col` ends up as  (PHP allows you to call `++` on a single letter, like `$col = 'A'; $col++; echo $col; // 'B'`, or `$col = 'Z'; $col++; echo $col; // 'AA'`)

Answer (score 1):

```
**Create headings in your file export**   
public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'Id',
            'Name',
            'Unit',
            'Status',
            'Price',
            'Date'
        ];
   }


**Documentation:**
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/column-formatting.html
```